# JavaScript request to get Form model from Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, fetch-api

as my first project by myself, for a web dev course I am building a "clone" of a famous password manager.
It is a Django single page web app, using vanilla JavaScript for async request and content management.

**Preface:**

I created a model for the Login instance table

**Models.py**

```
class Login(models.Model):
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=False, null=False)
username = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
notes = ...
folder = ....
```

And from Django I was able to pass it through to the page as an empty ModelForm with correct formatting

**Forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Login
        fields = ('title', 'username', 'password', 'note', 'folder', 'protected', 'favorite',)
        widgets = {
            'password': PasswordInput,
            'note': Textarea(attrs={'rows':6, 'placeholder':"Add notes here..."}),
        }
```

it submits and saves it correctly.

**Problem**

I am now trying to add the possibility to edit the saved form without reloading, so I would need to create a textarea for each field, precompiled with the current value to be submitted.

I started trying to build the same thing from JavaScript when the  button is clicked, building a template **for each of the 7 field it has**, and entering the current value as the textarea value, **e.g.**

**script.js**

```
const titlearea = document.createElement('TEXTAREA');
       uriarea.setattribute('name', 'title');
       titlearea.setAttribute('maxlength', 80);
       titlearea.setAttribute('rows', 1);
       titlearea.style.resize = "none";
       titlearea.value = data.title;
       template.querySelector('.tag-title').append(titlearea);

// and this is just ONE
```

**Question:**

Is it possible from JavaScript to send a request to Django for the `LoginForm` to be passed as <s>JsonResponse</s> a Response??
Like sending a fetch GET request for the form and getting back the blank template with the correct formatting for *maxlength* etc??

i am getting `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable` or `TypeError: Object of type EntryForm is not JSON serializable` based on what I was able to think about doing.

I don't need it to be serialized, i would need to get an HTML form, but I can't seem to find how to do it or if it would be possible

This is my biggest project yet, and I'm just a beginner both in Django and Javascript, so I avoided React and any other framework

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `response.text()` was the answer I was looking for